# Spring security log or add custom message for each unathorized (access denied) request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have spring security applied like below:

```
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ctxPath1/**", "/ctxPath2/**", "/ctxPath3/**").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')");
```

All works fine here. i.e. user with any other role than ADMIN get access denied message (page/view). No issues here at all.

**Situation:**
I want to send a custom friendly message to view/page for each denied `/ctxPathX`. Something like - `You tried to access "Feature X" on which you dont have access. Click here to send a request to Administrator for this feature entitlement.`

Is that possible at all? If yes, where should I start looking and what options we have to achieve that?

**Summary**: Can I configure/code and send custom message to view(s) for each denied path individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-access-denied-page). You can add a custom handler (implements AccessDeniedHandler) to display an error page.

```
.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
```

Comment: Sweet.. I had visited the link you shared but overlooked. Silly me. Thanks so much for your help.